# How to inline set component background?

Tags: css, reactjs

```
function myImage() {
  return (<img src={require("./images/redlantern1.jpg")}  />)
}
```

In my return: I have this:

```
<Route exact path="/submitProperty" component={NavBar} />
<Route exact path="/submitProperty" component={submitProperty}/>
<Route exact path="/submitProperty" component={myImage}/>
```

NavBar should be on top of submitProperty and myImage, but I want myImage to serve as the background of submitProperty, rather than below it.

I have tried:

```
import redlantern from './images/redlantern1.jpg'
<Route exact path="/submitProperty" component={submitProperty} style={{backgroundImage:{redlantern}}}/>
```

but it didn't work.

Thank you

edit:

I was able to set the background with

```
    <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', backgroundImage: 'url(https://media1.tenor.com/images/318cab8d6fecd9181284239fffadf69e/tenor.gif?itemid=12316453)'}}> 
      <Route exact path="/submitProperty" component={submitProperty} />
    </div>
```

but it only covers part of the page rather than the entire page..

edit:

```
  <Route exact path="/submitProperty" component={NavBar} />
  <Route exact path="/submitProperty" component={submitProperty} />
  <Route exact path="/submitProperty" component={myImage}/>
```

gives me https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgQbo.jpg

but I Want the image to be in the background filling up the entire page, with the form on top of it

Comment: Can you share any working fiddle for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: I have made another edit and posted image of what it gives me. Thank you

Comment: I think it's a CSS related issue and It cannot be resolve by reviewing screenshot. Try to deploy your on any server. Then share the link. Thanks